# Default *key* when accessing dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Python has `dict.get(key, default_value)` which will attempt to retrieve the value under `key`, and if no `key` is found, give `default_value` instead.

I am trying to retrieve some keys, which I cannot guarantee to actually exist. However, because the `default_value` is determined at run time, I cannot easily provide the default value either. What I *can* guarantee is that whatever the default value is, it will be under `my_key`. How can I implement this with a simple Python one-liner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is `my_dict.get(key, my_dict[my_key])`.